# Product Image misaligned, not displaying correctly

Tags: product-images, magento-2.1.8

I wanted to remove the images so I resized the images in Magento luma `view.xml` as images `<width>0</width>` and same for `height` everywhere and true values as all false.

Now it is perfect for me and kept `no image` in Placeholder image at admin so that default `image.jpg` of **262x262** is picked every time when the product is clicked and product image displayed.

Now in 2.1.8 which is running on web host server, I overwrite the **262x262** default placeholder image.jpg with another one of same **262x262** but image is not displaying aligned and as perfect as it was on fresh installation..it is showing misaligned, little below the actual placeholder position.

To verify if issue is with web host, I checked with 2.1.7 installed at localhost of local computer and there default placeholder image was showing correct, at the right position and aligned.

I don't know what's going wrong with 2.1.8.

Also I revert the changes in 2.1.8 to default but still placeholder image showing incorrect position even after clearing Magento cache, reindexing and clear browser image.

I haven't change any value in any file other than `view.xml`.

Please refer the images attached here, need help. [image: Main issue in 2.1.8]

[image: Displaying Correct on local computer /localhost 2.1.7]

[![Changes done in 2.1.8 view.xml][3]][3]

[![Changes done in 2.1.8 view.xml][4]][4]